# Rails4 asset precompiling fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

In my application, I have various themes user can select from for a particular web page. These themes just differs in terms of color and font types only. So in order to not to repeat the css declaration, I have created a scss file containing common css declarations `ztheme.css.scss` that contains common css styles in all themes. And I have various themes scss files (e.g. `silver.css.scss`, `melon.css.scss` - shown below) with merely variables value defined for color and font type. In all these theme scss files, you can see at the bottom it imports the common `ztheme.css.scss` as `@import 'ztheme'`. So that whene these themes files get compiled, they will have common css styling with appropriate color and font types value.

`silver.css.scss`

```
$nav_bg_color: #F6F6F6;
$page_font: 'Sintony', sans-serif;
$page_txt_color: #000033;
@import 'ztheme';
```

`melon.css.scss`

```
$nav_bg_color: #F2F6C6;
$page_font: 'Arial', verdana;
$page_txt_color: #628002;
@import 'ztheme';
```

`ztheme.css.scss`

```
body{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: $nav_bg_color;
  font-family: $page_font;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  color: $page_txt_color;
}
```

The problem is when I deploy this code on heroku and asset precompiling kicks off and then it fails in `ztheme.css.scss` because it looks for the value of variables defined in it. and throw this error:

```
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$nav_bg_color".
remote:        /tmp/build_ded002611a0752bd96038a671fd8051c/app/assets/stylesheets/themes/ztheme.css.scss:9
```

However you can see, `ztheme` is being imported in every theme files, so when `ztheme` will be imported in those files, these zthemes' value should get populated properly and it should not throw `Undefined variable` error.

**How to solve this problem?**

I have structured my assets as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine what code is in what file from your code, but I think you may have done your @imports backwards. Try importing all of your themes into 'ztheme.css.scss', because they're where you define '$nav-bg-color'.

This might not be an all-inclusive solution, but somewhere to start from.

I hope this helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, finally I found the solution. I had to add a `default` value for these variables in `ztheme.css.scss` that gets overridden in theme specific scss

```
$nav_bg_color: #F1C5CE  !default;
$page_font: Arial, Verdana !default;
$page_txt_color: #459823 !default;

body{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: $nav_bg_color;
  font-family: $page_font;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  color: $page_txt_color;
}
```